# Columns outside WITH ROLLUP clause

Tags: mysql

I know that in some dialects of SQL you can do something like that:

```
SELECT A, B, C, SUM(D)
FROM E
GROUP BY ROLLUP (A, B), C;
```

As you can see, one column is outside the `ROLLUP` operator.

I tried to do something similar in MySQL, but:

```
SELECT A, B, C, SUM(D)
FROM E
GROUP BY A, B WITH ROLLUP, C
```

...doesn't work.

Is there a way to do this in MySQL?

Comment: `GROUPING SETS` would have been nice, but don't think MySQL supports that either

Comment: [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  GROUP BY Modifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

Comment: What do you expect those phrases to do?  Perhaps a subquery can achieve the same goal.